# Twisted getPage, exceptions.OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I'm trying to run the following script with about 3000 items. The script takes the link provided by `self.book` and returns the result using `getPage`. It loops through each item in `self.book` until there are no more items in the dictionary.

Here's the script:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import getPage
from twisted.web.error import Error
from twisted.internet.defer import DeferredList

import logging
from src.utilitybelt import Utility

class getPages(object):
    """ Return contents from HTTP pages """

    def __init__(self, book, logger=False):
        self.book = book
        self.data = {}
        util = Utility()
        if logger:
            log = util.enable_log("crawler")

    def start(self):
        """ get each page """
        for key in self.book.keys():
            page = self.book[key]
            logging.info(page)

            d1 = getPage(page)

            d1.addCallback(self.pageCallback, key)
            d1.addErrback(self.errorHandler, key)
            dl = DeferredList([d1])

        # This should stop the reactor
        dl.addCallback(self.listCallback)

    def errorHandler(self,result, key):
        # Bad thingy!
        logging.error(result)
        self.data[key] = False
        logging.info("Appended False at %d" % len(self.data))

    def pageCallback(self, result, key):
        ########### I added this, to hold the data:
        self.data[key] = result
        logging.info("Data appended")
        return result

    def listCallback(self, result):
        #print result
        # Added for effect:
        if reactor.running:
            reactor.stop()
            logging.info("Reactor stopped")
```

About halfway through, I experience this error:

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py",       line 303, in _handleSignals

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 205, in __init__

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 138, in __init__

exceptions.OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

As of right now, I'll try to run the script with less items to see if that resolves the issue. However, there must be a better way to do it & I'd really like to learn.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please provide the definition for `getPage`? Looks like you're not disposing of something cleanly

Comment: Here's the documentation for [getPage](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.getPage.html). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah right, yes! I think this will be related to you creating all of your deferreds in one go - I would have ~5-10 active concurrently and create new ones in pageCallback as they complete. I think you're exhausting the number of concurrent connections your OS will handle. It's also less likely to be an efficient solution

Comment: You should really not be using getPage; it has a lot of problems, some serious security problems among them.  Instead, you might want to use twisted.web.client.Agent, or the nice high-level convenience library for it,  [`treq`](http://treq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting the open file descriptors limit (ulimit -n) which is likely to be 1024.
Each new getPage call opens a new file handle which maps to the client TCP socket opened for the HTTP request. You might want to limit the amount of getPage calls you run concurrently. Another way around is to up the file descriptor limit for your process, but then you might still exhaust ports or FDs if self.book grows beyond 32K items.